# How to query LocalDateTime with LocalDate?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, java-time, spring-repositories

I've got a class which contains an atttribute of java.time.LocalDateTime type.

```
public class MyClass{
    // ...
    private LocalDateTime fecha;
    // ...
}
```

I'm using Spring Data repositories. What I want to accomplish is to query entities according to a date:

```
@Service
public interface IRepository extends CrudRepository<MyClass, UUID> {
    // ...
    public void deleteByFecha(LocalDate fecha);
    // ...
}
```

But this does not work, as an exception is thrown:

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [2016-10-05] did not match expected type [java.time.LocalDateTime (n/a)];

So the question is how can I query MyClass in database by *fecha* but with a LocalDate?

*EDIT*
Just in case somebody faces the same issue, I've come up with one solution: modify the Repository's method so that it looks as follows:

```
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
// ...

@Service
public interface IRepository extends CrudRepository<MyClass, UUID> {

    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query("DELETE FROM MyClass mtc WHERE YEAR(mtc.fecha)=?1 AND MONTH(mtc.fecha)=?2 AND DAY(mtc.fecha)=?3")
    public void deleteByFecha(Integer year, Integer month, Integer day);

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this (not tested):

```
public interface IRepository extends CrudRepository<MyClass, UUID> {
    // ...
    default void delByFecha(LocalDate fecha) {

        deleteByFechaBetween(fecha.atStartOfDay(), fecha.plusDays(1).atStartOfDay());

    }

    void deleteByFechaBetween(LocalDateTime from, LocalDateTime to);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Another possible solution I didn't think about... Thanks

Comment: It worked for me. Can I ask why default is needed in this case?

Comment: Thank you, you saved me some time :)

Answer (score 2):

Zombie Thread, but thought I'd throw my solution into the ring.

I had a similar issue, I ended up using a Hibernate `@Formula`

For example:

```java
class MyClass {

  private LocalDateTime fecha;

  /* fecha referenced within the annotation should be the column name. 
   * So, if it's different the Java field name (i.e. fecha_dtm or something), 
   * make sure to use it.
  */
  @Formula("CAST(fecha as DATE)") 
  private LocalDate fechaDate;

}
```

Then your repository:

```java
public interface IRepository extends CrudRepository<MyClass, UUID> {
  deleteByFechaDate(LocalDate fecha); // note it's FechaDate, not Fetcha
}
```

Try to stick to ANSI SQL compliant functions (`CAST` is SQL-92 compliant, so pretty widely accepted) to keep things consistent across database implementations. However, DB specific functions can be used, you'll just lose portability.

Hopefully this helps you!

Comment: The CAST on pl/sql doesn't work as expected, it still returns a datetime. I suggest using TRUNC

Answer (score 2):

I had a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61997577/how-to-query-jpa-localdatetime-field-with-a-localdate-value/61998055) today (I was making SELECT, not a DELETE) and after posting it on here, I came up with two solutions:

```
@Query(value = "DELETE FROM MyClass mc WHERE DATE(fecha) =:fecha", nativeQuery = true)
public void deleteByFecha(LocalDate fecha);
```

Alternatively, following [Cepr0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5380322/cepr0)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43981519/3450862), I tested with success his solution:

```
default void deleteByFecha(LocalDate fecha) {
    deleteByFechaBetween(fecha.atStartOfDay(), fecha.plusDays(1).atStartOfDay());

}

void deleteByFechaBetween(LocalDateTime from, LocalDateTime to);
```

Answer (score 1):

I know that this one is a old issue, but for the future, who is with the same problem can use this solution:

```
 default void delByFecha(@RequestParam(name = "date") @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE) LocalDate date)
```

It's works perfectly!