# How to use cast in HQL OR JPQL?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpql

**Hi,my HQL query is like this.**

```
 @Query("select A.TheaterName as theater,A.MovieName as movie,CAST(A.ShowDateTime as showDate)" +
         "(select sum(TicketPrice) from ccmsfdb2.HallApi.TicketTransaction where \n" +
         "CAST(ShowDateTime as date)=CAST(A.ShowDateTime as Date) AND\n" +
         " MovieName=A.MovieName and TheaterName=A.TheaterName and TicketStatusValue=1) as collection\n" +
         "from CCMSFDB2.HallApi.TicketTransaction A where A.MovieName='Sanju'  \n" +
         "and A.TheaterName='QFX Jai Nepal' \n" +
         "group by CAST(A.ShowDateTime as date),A.TheaterName,A.MovieName,CAST(A.ShowDateTime as Date)   order by showDate DESC")
    List<MovieCollectionAccordingToTheaaterDto> getMovieCollectionAccordingToTheater();\
```

In the above query ,I have tried to cast showdatetime as date and sum the gross collection according to date but cast is not supported in hql and i don't want to use native query.

Comment: I don't think casting is possible without native query, native query solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/61997704/4207306

Answer (score 0):

`CAST` is supported in HQL, given that the underlying DB supports it.

Try full-qualified class name for Date(`java.util.Date`) inside the `@Query` expression.

**See :**
1. [HQL Expressions](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions)